# How to set lang attribute on html element with Nuxt?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-meta

Using the file `nuxt.config.js` file, `head` contents can be customized to add some meta, or other things:

```
module.exports = {
  /*
  ** Headers of the page
  */
  head: {
    title: 'awesome title',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: 'Nuxt.js project' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ]
  },
  ...
}
```

But I can't find anything in the documentation to set attributes on the `html` element -- I want to set the `lang` attribute. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Try [Declaring language in HTML tag · Issue #388 · nuxt/nuxt.js](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/388)

Comment: @yuriy636 it worked. Would you make it an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Source: [Declaring language in HTML tag · Issue #388 · nuxt/nuxt.js](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/388)

`head` supports a `htmlAttrs` property. It will map each **key:value** of the object as **attribute:value**

```
module.exports = {
  head: {
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: 'en'
    }
  }
}
```

*How to do this when using i18n: [Setting the language attribute when using i18n and Nuxt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50656053/setting-the-language-attribute-when-using-i18n-and-nuxt)*

Comment: What if you are using different languages (locales)?

Comment: This also work with Body bodyAttrs and Head headAttrs

Comment: Yes, like @JMK said, what if using i18n with different locales ?

Comment: @Vinny Looks like he created a separate question for that. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50656053/setting-the-language-attribute-when-using-i18n-and-nuxt

Answer (score 19):

In Nuxt 3 type in the component

```js
<script setup>
useHead({
  htmlAttrs: {
    lang: 'en',
    style: 'font-size: 13px'
  }
})
</script>
```

https://v3.nuxtjs.org/getting-started/seo-meta/

Comment: Thanks! This isn't documented in https://v3.nuxtjs.org/getting-started/seo-meta/

Comment: It is mentioned, but now displying is bugged https://github.com/nuxt/framework/issues/9178

Comment: I see, they changed link to docs and now there are two different methods (in component and in nuxt config), in april there was no option to add it by globally like today.

Answer (score 12):

Add htmlAttrs to `nuxt.config.js`

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    app: {
        head: {
            htmlAttrs: {
                lang: 'en',
            },
            title: 'title',
            charset: 'utf-8',
            meta: [],
            link: [],
        }
    },
})
```