# Setting the language attribute when using i18n and Nuxt?

Tags: vue.js, internationalization, nuxt.js, vue-i18n, nuxt-i18n

With Nuxt, you can set the language HTML attribute inside the **nuxt.config.js** file like so:

```
module.exports = {
  head: {
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: 'en-GB',
},
... etc etc
```

However, what should you do if you have a multi-language app? Is there any way to set the language attribute based on the locale?

I thought that maybe `document.documentElement.setSttribute('lang', 'language-code')` would work, but as nuxt is rendered server side, it doesn't seem to have access to the documentElement object.

Thanks

Answer (score 13):

Maybe I'm late, but it's just as simple as this chunk of code in your `layouts/default.vue`:

```
export default {
    // other code...
    head() {
        return {
            htmlAttrs: {
                lang: this.$i18n.locale
            }
        }
    },
    // other code...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using nuxt-i18n, you can call `$nuxtI18nHead` with `addSeoAttributes: true` in your default layout. This will set the `lang` attribute as well as some other language-specific header attributes for better SEO.

```js
export default {
    head() {
        return this.$nuxtI18nHead({ addSeoAttributes: true })   
    },
}
```

Source: https://i18n.nuxtjs.org/seo#improving-performance

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Install vue-i18n npm

```
 npm install vue-i18n
```

> 2. create a plugin in the plugin dir and add the below code. Eg: i18n.js

```
import Vue from 'vue' 

import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n'

Vue.use(VueI18n)

export default ({app}) => {
    app.i18n = new ueI18n({
        locate: 'ja',
        fallbackLocale: 'en',
        silentTranslationWarn: true,
        message: {
            'ja': require('~/locale/ja/translations.json'),
             'en': require('~/locale/en/translations.json')
        }
    })
}
```

> 3. Include this plugin in your nuxt.config.js file and set the lang

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: [{src: '~plugins/i18n.js', injectAs: 'i18n'}],
    head: {
        htmlAttrs: {
            lang: this.$i18n.locale,
        }
    }
}
```

> 4. translations.json file contain your translation in json format

```
{
    "hello": "Hello World"
}
```

> 5. In component file, you can access the translation as below

```
<p>{{ $t("hello") }}</p>
```

*Note: I didnt tested the code*

Comment: Thanks, although I don't think this actually sets the Language attribute in 
 the *<html>* tag. I'm asking because this seems to be important for screenreaders etc (and Wave shows it as an error).

Comment: this is not what OP asked for

Comment: How can you use this.$i18n within nuxt.config.js? This does not work for me.

Comment: Okay. You can use this.$i18n for head, but head must be a function returning an object instead of only being an object.

Comment: As @remino said earlier, `$i18n` is not available through `nuxt.config.js` so the answer won't work as expected.