# Nuxt Lang attribute config

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxt-i18n

Trying to specify my language with nuxt,

Result is weird :

```
<html lang="en" data-n-head="%7B%22lang%22:%7B%22ssr%22:%22en%22%7D%7D"><head>
```

config is simple but doesnt work :

> ```
>  head: {
>   title: 'test',
>    htmlAttrs: {
>  lang: 'it',
> ```
>
> },

any idea ?

Comment: I am having the same problem did you manage to solve?

Answer (score 3):

Are you possibly using the Nuxt PWA module together?
If so, you need to configure the language settings in the PWA module settings as well.

```
pwa: {
  manifest: {
    lang: 'it',
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48238472/how-to-set-lang-attribute-on-html-element-with-nuxt) that should work (don't have nuxt at hand to try). Are you exporting it correctly, that's in `nuxt.config.js`, right?

```js
module.exports = {
  head: {
    htmlAttrs: { lang: 'en' },
    title: 'awesome title',
...
```

Comment: I tried same problem with module.exports = {

  
  head: {
    title: 'test',
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: 'it',
    },